# How to get original type names for elementary types in auto generated fields of particular type in Resharper 8.1?

Tags: c#, resharper, typename, type-alias

Everybody knows that we can use `property with backing field` feature in `Resharper` and get something like that:

```
public Int32 TestField { get; set; }
```

Resharper is here.

```
public Int32 TestField
{
    get { return _testField; }
    set { _testField = value; }
}
private int _testField;
```

**int** is the problem. I don't need this alias, I want to get **Int32** type for this operation. 
The same if talk about autogenerated method stubs. For example,

```
void AutogeneratedStub(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

So again I have **object** instead of **Object**

How can I do that? In what options? Version of Resharper is 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-5662), it's planned for R# 9.0